# missing partition in server centos 6.1

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

I used the command `df-h` on my centos 6.1
here's the output

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       50G  2.3G   45G   5% /
tmpfs                 5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   35M  425M   8% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home
                      2.0T  199M  1.9T   1% /home
```

i found out that the hard disk is two terabyte. but when I used the command `cat /proc/partitions | more`

here's the output

```
[root@localhost sysconfig]# cat /proc/partitions | more
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0 4293656576 sda
   8        1     512000 sda1
   8        2 2146970624 sda2
 253        0   52428800 dm-0
 253        1   14417920 dm-1
 253        2 2080120832 dm-2
```

you could see on the first line. it is **4396.7 GB** . why is it i could only see is 2TB? how could i find my missing another 2TB and make it a partition.

I also use the command `lsblk`

here is the output

```
[root@localhost ~]# lblsk
-bash: lblsk: command not found
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO MOUNTPOINT
sda                           8:0    0     4T  0
ââsda1                        8:1    0   500M  0 /boot
ââsda2                        8:2    0     2T  0
  ââVolGroup-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0    50G  0 /
  ââVolGroup-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0  13.8G  0 [SWAP]
  ââVolGroup-lv_home (dm-2) 253:2    0     2T  0 /home
sr0                          11:0    1  1024M  0
```

using the parted /dev/sda i type the `print free` command

here's the output

```
(parted) print free
Model: DELL PERC 6/i (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 4397GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
        32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB           Free Space
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   primary  ext4         boot
 2      525MB   2199GB  2198GB  primary               lvm
        2199GB  4397GB  2198GB           Free Space
```

Comment: You said your disk is a 2TB drive so why do you expect there to be 4TB?

Comment: @mikea Opps sorry. I've updated my post.

Comment: what does the following report: parted /dev/sda unit TB print free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong, sorry. As you can see in `parted print free` output you have 2 MBR partitions - `boot` and `lvm` and 2198GB free space (last row).

If you want to use all of your space you have to use [GPT partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table). These partitions as opposed to MBR partition that can only address up to 2TB, can address your whole disk and up to 8 ZiB (zebibytes).

You can try to convert MBR partition table to GPT ([example 1](http://www.nosql.se/2012/05/converting-from-mbr-based-partitioning-to-gpt-guid-partition-table-while-online/), [example 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from)), though I strongly recommend to backup your data.

Comment: using the gpt partition, do i have to reformat my server before using GPT partitions?

Comment: You might not need to reformat, because it's possible to extend your Volume group, then extend logical volume and finally extend your ext filesystem with `resize2fs`, but, please, be careful.

Comment: ok i'll try this. thanks for this. well it's a new installed centos, so maybe if a got some error or mistakes, i'll just reformat it again.

Answer (score 1):

You are using tools showing info from different layers of your system and interpreting it wrong.

`df`, according to man page, will display the space available on all currently mounted **file systems**.

`/proc/partitions` holds info about partitions on your **drive** - physical device. This file shows you size of your drive as number of **blocks**. Usually, on HDD block size is a size of sector - 512 bytes.

So, sda size of 4293656576 is size in blocks, not kilobytes.

4293656576 blocks = (4293656576 / 2 ) kilobytes = 2146828288 KiB =  2047.375 GiB, or 2198.352 GB.

Assuming 1 GiB = `1 * 2^30`, 1 GB = `1 * 10^3`.

If you want to see size of your disk use `fdisk -l <device name>`.

Comment: sir. according to my co-worker. they bought 4TB. and installed centOS6.1. and they said that the centos has an problem in creating a 4TB so they create a partition 2TB. and the other is still raw. but i can't seem to find it. i used fdisk -l and the output is `Disk /dev/sda: 4396.7 GB, 4396704333824 bytes`